# Не работают анимации material в шаблоне Angular asp.net core 2

Tags: angular2, asp.net-core, .net-core, angular4

Хочу добиться анимаций кнопок [как в первом примере](https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview)

Кнопка в компоненте с кодом `<button md-button>Click me!</button>` не имеет анимации.
В файле "app.module.shared" подключен модуль `MdButtonModule`. Подключить модуль `BrowserAnimationsModule` в этом файле нельзя, возникает ошибка рендера. Подключаю его в файле "app.module.browser", это не дает никаких результатов.

Как настроить работу анимаций angular material в шаблоне angular asp.net core 2?

Comment: убедись, что осуществлен и импорт `import { MdButtonModule } from '@angular/material';` и декларация в `@NgModule({imports: [MdButtonModule]})` в `app.module`

Comment: @Vadim, он подключен и работает. Не работают анимации

Comment: А ваша проблема связана с asp.net core 2? Если вы просто запускаете через ng serve работает?

Comment: Ok, у меня было подобное поведение (отсутствие анимации) как раз из-за некорректного декларирования. Показывает ли консоль браузера какие-либо ошибки? И я склонен согласиться с предыдущим оратором Alexandr'ом, что скорее всего asp.net тут не причем. Когда делаешь build после запуска команды `ng s`, то тоже может появляться ряд ошибок в терминале, есть что-то подобное?

Comment: @Vadim никаких ошибок нету. Думаю что проблема в шаблоне, а именно из-за серверного рендеринга (этот механизм ведь так называется?). Подключил Material Design Lite, все равно его хотел использовать.